# Spread array destructuring in react-native errored

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, babeljs

The following code:

```
const [ ...routes, currentRoute ] = props.routes
```

Produces an `unexpected token` error on such line.

Why is this?

Comment: A syntax error is not "crashing". It's just a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, editing title as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [rest operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Rest_operator) only at the end of the destructuring expression, e.g.:

```
const [ currentRoute, ...routes ] = props.routes.reverse()
```

It is stated in [ECMAScript 2015 Spec.#Destructuring Assignment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-destructuring-assignment), it could be hard to read but look at `ArrayAssignmentPattern` structure.

Comment: Then, this only applies to destructuring? I have seen and used other spread expressions such as the shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: @jsdario it is not spread expression. It is rest assignment expression which is very similar to rest parameters.